# Run a command from a web page

Tags: php, html

Im working on a project where you type in a youtube video link (eg. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKpLtHw7IKQ) and it downloads the video to the same directory as the html.

I already have a shell script that i can run in terminal but now I need to set up a webpage where i paste the link and click a button and it downloads it. On the server side it should look like this: `./youtube-mp3 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKpLtHw7IKQop`

can any one help me with the html/php code? I'm new to html and php stuff.

Comment: What do you mean by download?  You can't download youtube videos as far as I know..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use exec():

```
<?php
exec("./youtube-mp3 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qKpLtHw7IKQop");
?>
```

Comment: how do i set up a text field so the user can change the video link?

Comment: be VERY careful if you let user input drive something sent to exec() on the server. Do  web search for "command injection."

Comment: in the html write: <form action="{name of the php file}" method="post">Video link: <input name="link"/> <input type="submit" value="Submit"/></form> and in the php file write <?php if(isset($_POST['link'])){
exec("./youtube-mp3 ".$_POST['link']);
} ?>
However, as tom_yes_tom says, you must be very careful and check if it's actually a link or a malicious injection